# Get BuiltInParameterId from BuiltIn Parameter ElementId in Revit

Tags: revit-api, revit

Is there a Way to get the BuiltInParameterId (Ex:BuiltInParameter.SHEET_SIZE) 
from a Parameter ElementId.

I have a number extracted from an Schedule Field (-1010106)
and I want to get the BuildInParameter-id.
Currently I am doing it like this:

BIPdic = {i.value__ : i for i in BuiltInParameter.GetValues(BuiltInParameter)}
bipid= BIPdic[-1010106]

I could not find an easier way. (Its easy, but I have to built a dictionary 
from all (over 3000 BuiltInParameters)).

THX
tillbaum

Comment: I have an elementId as an IntegerValue,  ex: -1010106 
and I know its a  BuiltInparameter. 

Now I want to get the BuiltInParameter-Id from the BuiltInParameter Enum, which is this: 
Ex: ALL_MODEL_INSTANCE_COMMENTS

How can I do that. Is this even possible? 

"ElementId " does exactly the opposite. 

ElementId(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_INSTANCE_COMMENTS)
 
returns:  <Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementId object at 0x00000000000003D6 [-1010106]>

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure I know what you mean. Check out the description of the [`ElementId` constructor taking a `BuiltInParameter` input argument](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/cde49e84-86c6-1fc8-2c50-e5fc6b627470.htm).

You can also take a look at the [built-in parameter checker BipChecker](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.34) and its [BipChecker GitHub repo](https://github.com/jeremytammik/BipChecker/tree/master/BipCheckerhttps://github.com/jeremytammik/BipChecker/tree/master/BipChecker). It iterates over all built-in parameter values and tries to retrieve a parameter value for each one.

That sounds pretty similar to what you are after with your dictionary.

Comment: "ElementId " does exactly the opposite. 

ElementId(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_INSTANCE_COMMENTS)
 
returns:  <Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementId object at 0x00000000000003D6 [-1010106]>

Comment: if you want the opposite of that, you can convert `ElementId` to `int` and cast `int` to `BuiltInParameter`:  `ElementId id = ???; BuiltInParameter bip = ( BuiltInParameter) ( id.IntegerValue );`

Comment: Wow, ok, That looks easy. Thank you. I'll try this definitly. Thats C#.  I am using IronPython and RPS. 
(I just begann studying a C# book, this will take a while).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BuiltInParameter parameter = (BuiltInParameter)Enum.ToObject(typeof(BuiltInParameter), paramIntValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat old now, but one of the ways this can be done is via an explicit cast:

```
public BuiltInParameter RetrieveBIP(Parameter param)
{
    return (BuiltInParameter)param.Id.IntegerValue;
}
```

of course, these days they have since migrated to use ForgeTypeIds for everything, and ElementIds have gone from int to long data type.